# JavaScript lost the value of innerHTML

Tags: javascript

Good Evening all

I have this JS function ()

```
function changeEd(id)
{
x = document.getElementById(id);
if (x.innerHTML == 'Post')
x.innerHTML = 'Posted'; 
else 
    x.innerHTML = 'Post'; 
}
```

Explanation : I am using this function to change `<a>Post</a>` To `<a>Posted</a>`
the function is Working fine and it's change from post to posted but when i reload the page It's returned to post .

Any solutions ??

Comment: You should use php to generate this code since javascript only does this for the current html page.

Comment: of course it sayes post... on beginning id might is empty or not really set... so you will land in false part of if.. try to cast this when page is loaded (document.loaded) because i think its called befor html is present

Comment: I used php and i inserted into my DB the values 1 if posted and the default would be 0 , but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

So assuming this page is not showing static content you could change you render logic to put the right value Post / Posted, if it is the case that you don't have that value still would be possible to call you function Change in the onload event for the control you want to update.